Intermittent first floor ceiling leak during rains
I have had kitchen ceiling leaks four times during heavy rains. But there have been other heavy rains where there haven't been kitchen ceiling leaks. The area is located near to a round section of windows. I was told that the roof over the round windows needs repairing for this leak. Is that the likely source? I already had the caulking around the windows redone, but there were a couple ceiling leaks since then.

It is a possible source.  Water leaks have the bad habit of travelling some distance before dropping down on a ceiling.  If possible should go into the attic and look for water stains on wood.  I have gone up on a roof to look/repair a water leak above the ceiling, only to find the actual leak 10 to 15 feet away.
